# FactoryGirls - NoMethodError: undefined method `location' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm just getting started in using FactoryGirls for Ruby and Rails and I don't understand why FactoryGirl is giving me this error when I try to run a test:

```
> Failures:
> 
>   1) Staffroom should create a valid staffroom from factory girl
>      Failure/Error: staffroom.should be_valid
>      NoMethodError:
>        undefined method `location' for nil:NilClass
>        ./app/models/location.rb:97:in `interpret_location_string'
>        ./app/models/location.rb:270:in `find_record_match'
>        ./app/models/location.rb:248:in `fetch_and_invalidate_cache_or_create'
>        ./app/models/location.rb:83:in `location_lookup'
>        ./app/concerns/has_location.rb:21:in `geocode_with_cache'
>        ./spec/models/staffroom_spec.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>        -e:1:in `<main>'
```

This is the code I have in my spec/models/staffroom_spec.rb:

```
describe Staffroom do
  it 'should create a valid staffroom from factory girl' do

    staffroom = build_stubbed(:group_staffroom)
    staffroom.should be_valid

    staffroom = build_stubbed(:industry_staffroom)
    staffroom.should be_valid

    staffroom = build_stubbed(:company_staffroom)
    staffroom.should be_valid
  end
end
```

And the code I have in spec/factories/staffrooms.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :staffroom do

        name { Faker::Company.name }

        location 'NEW YORK, NY, 13123'

        factory :industry_staffroom do
            staffroom_type 'Industry'
        end

        factory :company_staffroom do
            staffroom_type 'Company'
        end

    end
end
```

I guess I'm just confused as to why FactoryGirl would go looking in under models/location.rb?? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the code from location.rb's line 97:

```
94  def self.interpret_location_string(location_string)
95    not_defined_loc = Location.where(city: "SYDNEY*").first
96
97    unless not_defined_loc.location == location_string
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is location an attribute of staffroom or a related class/object?  Also, I don't see where you have defined :group_staffroom.  Separately, I am not a big faker fan - you wind up removing transparency from your tests and if you have a data specific issue, you may go crazy trying to find it.

Comment: There is a location model, but it has no relation to the location attribute of staffroom. About :group_staffroom, its in my code, but I just didnt include it here in the example. Sorry about that. It looks exactly like factory :industry staffroom and factory :company_staffroom

Comment: So the staffroom model has attributes name, location and staffroom_type (all strings) and there is a location model, but the two models are not associated at all?  It might help to see staffroom.rb.

Comment: Yep, all that you said is correct. I don't think I can show you all of staffroom.rb because it is huge. But staffroom requires the attributes name, location and staffroom_type. It also requires a plan which is a model but I don't think that's going to affect this test.  Is there something specific I can share from staffroom.rb?

Comment: I was just trying to confirm no associations between staffroom and location.  Can you extract the relevant code from location.rb around the error (line 97)?

Comment: No problem, here's the code:
94  def self.interpret_location_string(location_string)
95    not_defined_loc = Location.where(city: "SYDNEY*").first
96
97      unless not_defined_loc.location == location_string

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code there?  It is very hard to read as a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: I've also noticed that there's a location attribute in the location.rb model. The .location code on line 97: "unless not_defined_loc.location" is accessing the Location model's location attribute.

Comment: I should have mentioned earlier, if you have any doubts, you can always specify the class explicitly `factory :staffroom, class: Staffroom do`.

Comment: If you don't get a location back on line 95, you will get the error you posted on line 97.  I think that is your issue.  It is hard for me to suggest a fix without seeing the whole method but hopefully this gets you back on track.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was't able to get it working with that code :( I'll have a look at the code on line 97, but the weird thing is that FactoryGirl shouldn't even be looking into that model. Am I right about that? Since I explicitly said it was class: Staffroom and there is no association between Staffroom and Location model

Comment: Are you familiar with byebug?  You can build a Staffroom in the rails console and use byebug to understand why/when that method is getting invoked.  For sure the code is dangerous, it will blow up if you don't get a location back from the query.

Comment: I'll have a look at byebug. Thanks for all your help steve.

Comment: Sure Frederick - happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

`Location.interpret_location_string` is getting invoked when you build a `Staffroom` and the query on line 95 appears to be returning no `Location` object.  You should check that you have an object before accessing its attributes.